# Clone of table header doesn't inherit width when table is bigger than the window

Tags: jquery

I am using this script to make my table headers stick to the top of the page when scrolling through the table:
http://cmcqueen1975.bitbucket.org/htmlFloatingTableHeader/tables.html

The problem is, when the table exceeds the window size, the table headers are still crammed in to 100% of the screen width. Then the headers don't line up with the cells they represent.
This can be seen in this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/UDNNr/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The css-width of the cloned `<tr/>` doesn't match the sum of the width of the cells inside, you don't need to set the width of the `<tr/>`
2. What you need is to set the table-layout-style of the table to "fixed"

Comment: Point 1. makes a lot of sense to me. I am stuck on point 2: I'd like to make use of the auto table-style, and I don't understand why this property is limiting the width of the <tr/> to the width of the screen.

I experimented with taking the witdh of the columns while table-style='auto' and applying them to the <th/>s then changing the table-style to fixed, but then even the original header becomes fixed to the screen width.

Comment: Here's an example of the above. (Behaving differently to how I just described, but the same as original configuration, despite changes) 
http://jsfiddle.net/DDSns/3/

Comment: Setting the <tr> to "-moz-max-content" fixed this issue.